# Setting default zoom in Thunderbird 91+ using JS

Tags: javascript, thunderbird

While Mozilla Firefox at last has gained a preference which allows to set Default Zoom level, Thunderbird still haven't got it. This is a significant accessibility issue.
There exist a hack which allows to set the desired zoom level using Browser Console in Firefox, it is described [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332275#c52). I supposed that similar approach would work in Thunderbird and found the working command:

```
ZoomManager.setZoomForBrowser(getBrowser(), 1.2);
```

If this command is run in Error Console (analog of Browser Console in Firefox and it can be launched by the same shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>), then 120% zoom will be applied to the letter preview pane (at least).
Now the problem is to run this command when Thunderbird starts. I installed [userChromeJS extension](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/userchromejs-2/) which is developed to support Thunderbird version 91+ and which will "load the contents of chrome/userChrome.js from the user's profile directory every time a window is opened" as is said in its description. Then I added the next code, found [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=12906383#p12906383) into `chrome/userChrome.js`:

```
(function() {

if (location == "chrome://messenger/content/messenger.xul") {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ZoomManager.setZoomForBrowser(getBrowser(), 1.2);
  }, 0);
}

})();
```

But it doesn't work, zoom isn't applied to the preview pane as when I run this command manually.
This code is wrong, but I'm not that good in JS to fix it myself.

**Update:** If I place the sole string into `userChrome.js`, as @james s. proposed, it works, but it affects only Thunderbird's Welcome screen, nothing more. When I switch to some message, its preview window isn't zoomed.  So this check regarding `messenger.xul` is possibly needed. It's OK that this JS code runs only once (zoom level persists when I switch between the letters), but it should run not on start, but on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

if you cut out everything but the line to set the zoom level, which is executed on application start, it should work.

ie, userChrome.js entire contents is just:

```
ZoomManager.setZoomForBrowser(getBrowser(), 1.2);
```

Comment: It works, but affects only the Welcome screen. I updated my original question.